# Get First & Last visible date in TMonthCalendar

Tags: delphi

Is there a way to figure out the first & last visible
dates in TMonthCalendar ? 
[image: As circled in green]

Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Use [`MonthCal_GetMonthRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774701.aspx):

> Retrieves date information (using SYSTEMTIME structures) that represents the high and low limits of a month calendar control's display.

```
var
  times: array[0..1] of TSystemTime;
......
MonthCal_GetMonthRange(MonthCalendar1.Handle, GMR_DAYSTATE, @times[0]);
```

After the call, `times[0]` is a system time record containing the first displayed day on the calendar, and `times[1]` describes the last displayed day.

For a calendar like the one in your screenshot, this would return 25th June and 7th October. If you passed `0` instead of `GMR_DAYSTATE` then you would get 1st July and 30th September.